# Real estate units allocation

Tags: algorithm

I’m searching for the right algorithm that helps me to allocate clients who are interested to buy our real estate units in a way that maximize our sales
So each client will set a list of choices/ priority from 1 to 5 for the units he/she interested in 1 the highest 5 the least we open an inventory of 400 to 500 units and usually we receive around 700 different clients each with five choices so how can I allocate these units to our clients in away that maximize the sales hopefully we sell all units and give every requested as higher as possible choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [matching problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)). You need to setup your data as a graph (preferably [bipartite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph)) and then run the matching algorithm to maximize your sales([objective function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_optimization#Optimization_problems)).

[Here](https://visualgo.net/en/matching) is a sample matching algorithm(Although this one only supports unweighted edges) to visualize how matching works.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice ..is there any tool that can help me to perform this task instead of building it from scratch